# Using 'require' package code to obtain datapackages on the fly in R

Tags: r, require, devtools, bioconductor

I am writing an R package that uses a variety of bioconductor annotation data packages. The specific data packages vary with the use-case. As such, I have a function which does something like this:

```
if (!require(biocpack_name, character.only=T)) {
    source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    BiocInstaller::biocLite(biocpack_name)
    require(biocpack_name , character.only=T)
}
```

biocpack_name can be several of ~30+ annotation data packages that are looked up based on the particular data being analysed. As such, I don't want to have to add each to 'Suggests' (Im not even sure that would work because the error is not for a package but rather a string specifying the package). R CMD CHK gives me this error:

```
'library' or 'require' call not declared from: ‘biocpack_name’
'library' or 'require' call to ‘biocpack_name’ in package code.
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, but a warning. It goes away if you use `character.only = TRUE` rather than `T` (I guess because the value of TRUE is known and cannot be re-assigned, but T is unknown and can be anything, including FALSE). But in addition follow the advice in the warning to use `requireNamespace()` (and not pollute the user search path); maybe `db = get(biocpack_name, getNamespace(biocpack_name))` will allow you to use the annotation package the way you'd like, e.g., `mapIds(db, ...)`.

If one were pedantic, adding the packages to the Enhances: field of the DESCRIPTION file would communicate that your package somehow works with the annotation packages, but does not result in installation of the package (e.g., for building the vignette) unless explicitly requested.

Comment: Changing T to TRUE resolved issue. Not sure approach suggested would work as package is loaded within one function but then used by another. Wouldn't 'db' be local to the function in which it was created?

Comment: yes, you'd have to give some thought to how your functions were designed; maybe the code above is called `get_db()`, returning the db symbol each time it is needed?

Comment: I tried to do as suggested but ran up against an error. For example, if `biocpack_name <- "hgu95av2.db"` and the returned object is called `db`. The following works fine to get some sample keys: `keys <- AnnotationDbi::keys(db)[1:5]`. However, both `AnnotationDbi::mapIds(db, keys, "SYMBOL", keytype="PROBEID")` and `AnnotationDbi::select(db, keys, "SYMBOL")` fail with `object 'hgu95av2ORGPKG' not found`

Comment: The issue seems to be with a required package (`org.Hs.eg.db`) that is loaded by `require("hgu95av2.db")` but not by `db = get(biocpack_name, getNamespace(biocpack_name))` . How to fix?

Comment: @aqwsde that seems like a bug in AnnotationDbi, which has been fixed in version 1.33.13. If you're writing a package for Bioconductor, follow-up on the [bioc-devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/bioc-devel).

Comment: Just a follow up that this issue appears to have been resolved in the latest release of Bioconductor.